# How to compare String with HashMap

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to compare input text with Hashmap key 
I have stored Latlang values in Array list.
And i have 1 Map in that i Stored the key as city name and their coordinates.
now i want to search city in hashmap so that i can mark that points on map

```js
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    CoordinatorLayout mainCoordinatorLayout;
    private MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    private ArrayList<LatLng> seawood = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<LatLng> andhe = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, LatLng>city = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();
    EditText text;
    Button search;

    public static final String TAG = "gplaces";

    // remember to change the browser api key
    public static final String GOOGLE_BROWSER_API_KEY = "AIzaSyC79f__haC6E7ZbuO7j9HULq3VGD3pX5-E";

    public static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_neighborhood);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        text =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
        search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search);


        LatLng seawoods = new LatLng(19.0221178,73.0343958);
        LatLng panvel = new LatLng(19.0221178,73.0343958);
        LatLng vashi = new LatLng(19.0221178,73.0343958);
        LatLng vadala = new LatLng(19.0221178,73.0343958);
        LatLng andheri = new LatLng(19.097671,72.8629984);
        LatLng bandra = new LatLng(19.0221178,73.0343958);
        LatLng chembur = new LatLng(19.0221178,73.0343958);
        LatLng sanpada = new LatLng(19.0221178,73.0343958);

        city.put("Seawood", seawoods);
        city.put("Panvel",panvel);
        city.put("Vashi",vashi);
        city.put("Vadala",vadala);
        city.put("Andheri",andheri);
        city.put("Bandra",bandra);
        city.put("Chembur",chembur);
        city.put("Sanpada",sanpada);

        seawood.add(new LatLng(19.0193544, 73.0602836));
        seawood.add(new LatLng(19.0193544,73.0602836));
        seawood.add(new LatLng(19.0157782,73.0532021));
        seawood.add(new LatLng(19.0157782,73.0532021));
        seawood.add(new LatLng(19.0043141,73.028374));

        andhe.add(new LatLng(19.1117702,72.8645361));
        andhe.add(new LatLng(19.1117702,72.8645361));
        andhe.add(new LatLng(19.1117702,72.8645361));

        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i = 0; i < city.size(); i++) {

                    if ( text.getText().toString().equals(city.containsKey(i))) {

                        set(mMap, city.values(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }
    private List<Map.Entry<String, LatLng>> getSearchResults() {
        List<Map.Entry<String, LatLng>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : city.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().startsWith(text.getText().toString())) {
                results.add(entry);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public void set(GoogleMap map, LatLng l){

        mMap = map;
        for (LatLng point : seawood) {
            options.position(point);
            options.title("someTitle");
            options.snippet("someDesc");
            map.addMarker(options);
        }
        LatLng seawoods = new LatLng(19.0221178,73.0343958);
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(seawoods));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        map.setMinZoomPreference(12.0f);
        map.setMaxZoomPreference(14.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;


        for (LatLng point : seawood) {
            options.position(point);
            options.title("someTitle");
            options.snippet("someDesc");
            googleMap.addMarker(options);
        }
        LatLng seawoods = new LatLng(19.0221178,73.0343958);
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(seawoods));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMinZoomPreference(12.0f);
        googleMap.setMaxZoomPreference(14.0f);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want strict comparisons? If so the hash map is directly build for that. Using variable names from your code:

```
LatLng result = city.get(text.getText().toString());
```

Alternatively, if you want more loose comparison, you have to iterate over your hash-map yourself. Say you want to find those entires that only begin with your search string and be case-insensitive, you'd do something like this:

```
    private List<Map.Entry<String, LatLng>> getSearchResults() {
    List<Map.Entry<String, LatLng>> results = new ArrayList<>();
      for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : city.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().startsWith(text.getText().toString().toLowerCase())) {
            results.add(entry);
        }
      }
    return results;
    }
```

This will return a `List` of size 0 or greater, containing `Map.Entry<String, LatLng>>`

To access the Xth item's data you would do:

```
String cityName = results.get(X).getKey();
LatLng cityLatLng = results.get(X).getValue();
```

**Edit to answer your edit:**

The things you put in your on-click function seems incorrect. I would do something like:

```
search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        List<Map.Entry<String, LatLng>> results = getSearchResults();
        if (results.size() > 0) {
            // in this case we have at least 1 result, so go to it
            set(mMap, results.get(0).getValue());
        } else {
            // in this case we have no results - handle it as you want
        }
    });
```

Comment: where shoul i use getSearch()

Comment: @Rahul You would run getSearchResults() from your Search button's on-click function.

Comment: Check now i have edited my class I want to set Latlang in OnMypReady

Comment: @Rahul : I edited my answer to match your edited question.

Comment: Thank you so much @M. Penchev